# How does speed actually work in galaxy of heroes?

Tags: star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes

In galaxy of heroes, how does speed actually work? I know it affects how quickly your turn meter grows, but how does it affect that growth?

If my speed is modified by 20 speed, what exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 5):

Speed is directly proportional to turn meter growth (there is a linear relationship), so there is no complicated formula like you might expect based on how other stats work.  A character needs a turn meter of at least 1000 in order to take a turn.

After a character's turn their turn meter is decreased by 1000 (and any bonus is added as appropriate based on their skills and the ability used) and then the game advances one step — every character's turn meter is increased by the amount of their Speed stat (factoring in any buffs/debuffs).  If any single character's turn meter hits or passes 1000, it's their turn.  Otherwise, the game advances another step; repeat.

If two or more characters reach/pass 1000 turn meter at the same time, the one with the highest value goes first (since [early February](https://forums.galaxy-of-heroes.starwars.ea.com/discussion/11842/speed-changes-and-poe-dameron)).  If there is a tie, who goes first is random.